# Show column contents referring from another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have a table named ants which contains these:

[image: contents of table ants]

Now I want to see the contents of the column `phone_info` which has an id of for example onexT1. I tried using:

```
SELECT phone_info WHERE id="onexT1" FROM ants;
```

but it returns an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id="onexT1" FROM  ants' at line 1
```

How do I do it? Thanks :)

Comment: `SELECT phone_info FROM ants WHERE id='onexT1'` ... `FROM` comes before `WHERE`.

Comment: Read a SQL tutorial, it will tell you the correct syntax of queries. SQL is generally very strict about the order of clauses, you can't reorder them, so write them exactly as the tutorial instructs.

Comment: Oh ok thanks I actually found this syntax online where FROM is on the last clause. Anyways thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes:

```
SELECT phone_info WHERE id = 'onexT1' FROM ants;
```